# AppleScript to run MS Word commands?

Tags: ms-word, applescript

Is there a way to run Microsoft Word commands (***button commands or any other, not macros***) with AppleScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To view an application's AppleScript Dictionary:

Open AppleScript Editor
File --> Open Dictionary
Select your application from the list

Commands that are not included in the Dictionary can often be accessed through System Events with keystrokes or menu items.

There is some good info [here](http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/3/E/13E8AE25-78F7-41A8-B252-F09C465CE29C/Word2004AppleScriptRef.pdf):